# ClamAV Milter service will not start after updating clamav-milter

Tags: postfix, redhat, clamav

I recently updated ClamAV. Here are the packages that were updated:

- clamav-db-0.99-3.el6.x86_64
- clamav-0.99-3.el6.x86_64
- clamd-0.99-3.el6.x86_64
- clamav-milter-0.99-3.el6.x86_64
- libpng-1.2.49-2.el6_7.x86_64

Now I get this in every three minutes in `/var/log/maillog`:

```
mail postfix/smtpd[5581]: warning: connect to Milter service unix:/var/run/clamav/clamav-milter.sock: Permission denied
```

And if I try start start the clamav-milter service I get this:

```
[root@mail log]# service clamav-milter start
Starting Clamav Milter Daemon: ERROR: Failed to change socket ownership to user clam
                                                       [FAILED]
```

I'm running Postfix with Red Hat Hat Enterprise Linux 6.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a fix. I needed to edit my `/etc/clamav-milter.conf` file and comment out the following:

```
# Run as another user (clamav-milter must be started by root for this option to work)                                                                          
#                                                                               
# Default: unset (don't drop privileges)                                        
#User clam
```

Now the clamav-milter service starts properly.